# Most open VR Headsets for developers

Tags: development, vr-headset

I am looking to build a system where many VR Headsets are remote controlled by one device on the same LAN. The idea is that all headsets boot directly into the slave app, which for now only shows a video after that is started on the remote control. Ideally I am looking for standalone devices like the Oculus Go, but some comfort like wireless could be sacrificed for improved usability.

I want that each slave VR Headset automatically searches the network for a master remote, so it can poll to download new videos from it. After all slaves have the video file it can be started from the remote to run on all devices simultaneously.

Which VR Headset brands are best used to design such an app? Many seem especially restricive about booting into a 3rd party app by default. Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you looking for PC, standalone, or mobile VR HMDs?

Comment: @Evan, Based on the quote *"boot directly into the slave app"* they are looking for a standalone VR headset with an OS/firmware that allows a custom app to run on boot. Something like that would get in front of the UX provided on some big-name headsets, so the dev-kit or specially licensed versions of the hardware may be necessary.

Comment: Updated the comment. @Romen got it exactly right. I feared something like that would be required. If you come across any devices that happen to allow that easily/cheaply please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oculus Go or Oculus Quest are probably your best bets. Put them in Kiosk mode to boot into your application, bypassing the traditional Oculus Home screen.

Here is an article with instructions: https://theslidefactory.com/kiosk-mode-oculus-quest/

Alternatively, Oculus is making an Enterprise Edition if you need more features and support: https://uploadvr.com/oculus-quest-enterprise-edition/

Comment: Just got notified of this old post through a vote. As an update, now with the forced facebook login with the quest, it is sadly unfeasible for my use-case :(